# Elasticsearch logstash configuration for multiple json (nested) file in a folder

Tags: json, elasticsearch, logstash, data-ingestion

I have a folder that contains json files as below format.

```
{
"name" : "test",
"Age" : 30,
"friends" : [
      {"friend1" : "test2",
       "age" : 25 },
      {"friend2" : "test3",
        "age" : 27}
           ],
"country" : "unknown"
}
```

I am trying to ingest these data to elasticsearch index.

I would like to know how the logstash configuration should look like.
much appreciated.

Comment: How do you intend to index these records?
Will you have multiple documents per file in elasticsearch?
In your sample json, each item in the friends list seem to have different field name for friend. Is this correct ?

Comment: Thank you for your response. sorry, fields are the same in friends list.
I want to index this as it is. (for one document). so single document per file.

Answer (score 0):

Your logstash configuration could look like the following.
Here I assumed the username is unique, and used it as the elastic document's id.

```
input {
    file {
        path => "/pathToMyJsonFiles/*.json"
        start_position => beginning
        codec => json
    }
}
filter {
    mutate {
        copy => { "name" => "userId" }
   }
}
output {
    elasticsearch {
       hosts => ["elasticHost:port"]
       index => "users_index"
       manage_template => false
       document_id => "%{[userId]}"
  }
}
```

Just note that the file input plugin, reads one logstash event per line, so if the json is formatted as your example, you may need to change the delimiter, or format your files to have one json object per line.Like this:

```
{"name":"User1","Age":30,"friends":[{"friend":"test2","age":25},{"friend":"test3","age":27}],"country":"unknown"}
{"name":"User2","Age":30,"friends":[{"friend":"test2","age":25}],"country":"unknown"}
```